# ASMedia SATA controller 106x not working under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, hardware, pci, sata

I've added PCIe ASMedia SATA controller to my PC. It's working fine under win10 but not with ubuntu.

lspci returned that:

```
01:00.0 IDE interface: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 0624 (rev 01) (prog-if 85 [PCI native mode-only controller, supports bus mastering])
Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1060
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
I/O ports at e040 [size=8]
I/O ports at e030 [size=4]
I/O ports at e020 [size=8]
I/O ports at e010 [size=4]
I/O ports at e000 [size=16]
Memory at df180000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Expansion ROM at df100000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: pata_acpi
```

Motherboard controller works fine under ahci:

```
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
Memory at df228000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Memory at df22d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
Memory at df22c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
```

Any ideas what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the `pata_acpi` module gets matched to the controller first, before the `ahci` module gets a chance to try.

Edit (or create) `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add the following line to it:

```
blacklist pata_acpi
```

Then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to propagate the change to the initramfs file.

Alternatively, edit `/etc/default/grub` to add `blacklist=pata_acpi` to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. In other words, find a line like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

then change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="blacklist=pata_acpi"
```

If there are already something inside the double quotes, add `blacklist=pata_acpi` within the quotes, separated from the existing part with a space, i.e. if you find:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="something=else"
```

then change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="something=else blacklist=pata_acpi"
```

In both cases, after making the change, run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate the actual GRUB configuration file.

On the next boot, the `pata_acpi` module should not be loaded for the ASMedia SATA controller, and so the `ahci` module will get a chance to claim it.

Answer (score 1):

> According to
> https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:1b21-0612-1b21-1060,
> an ASMedia SATA controller 106x is a **SATA** controller, not a
> **PATA** device.
>
> Therefore it works with AHCI.

I think the question is, how to set the kernel to use ahci driver instead of pata_acpi. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Created an account so I could comment here, because I have been battling this one for a while with the same card under Ubuntu.

There's a switch on the card. Shut down the computer, move it to AHCI (Boot). Everything shows up. Run LSPCI again, and LSBLK to verify your devices are there.

Before:

```
IDE interface: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061 SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
```

After:

```
SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
```