# ASmedia SATA controller PCIe card not working on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, modprobe, sata

I am having the same issue as this question:
[ASMedia SATA controller 106x not working under ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665630/asmedia-sata-controller-106x-not-working-under-ubuntu)

However, the answer there did not work for me.  I have an ASMedia PCIe SATA card installed, and it appears to be claimed by the pata_acpi module:

```
sudo lspci -vvvnn
```

```
01:00.0 IDE interface [0101]: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:0624] (rev 01) (prog-if 85 [PCI native mode-only controller, supports bus mastering])
        Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device [1b21:1060]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
        Region 0: I/O ports at e040 [size=8]
        Region 1: I/O ports at e030 [size=4]
        Region 2: I/O ports at e020 [size=8]
        Region 3: I/O ports at e010 [size=4]
        Region 4: I/O ports at e000 [size=16]
        Region 5: Memory at fea80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Expansion ROM at fea00000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <2us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 5GT/s, Width x2, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (downgraded)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
                         10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [800 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Kernel modules: pata_acpi
```

This is despite that I think I blacklisted the pata_acpi module in both /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and /etc/default/grub:

```
more /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac

# blacklisted to prevent SATA card form ASMedia from loading it (when it shouldn't)
blacklist pata_acpi
```

```
more /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="blacklist=pata_acpi"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

And I have also run the commands to update the initramfs and grub:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

Any idea what might be preventing the blacklisting from taking effect?

Many thanks!

Comment: First step is to check if `pata_acpi` is really a module for your kernel, or it's inbuilt. Look at the kernel configuration, or `/lib/modules`.

Comment: Thanks.  The kernel config file contains `CONFIG_PATA_ACPI=m`, and I found `pata_acpi.ko` under `/lib/modules/5.4.0-91-generic/kernel/drivers/ata/`.  So I take it then that `pata_acpi` is indeed a module, and should be blacklistable?

Comment: After also reading this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495204/blacklisting-modules-in-modprobe-d-and-kernel-params-is-not-working, it seems that `pata_acpi` is in fact blacklisted; it's mention in the `lspci` output is only under `Kernel modules:` and not under `Kernel driver in use:`  indicating (I think) that the `pata_acpi` module is supposed to support the card. However, I think we want the `ahci` module instead. How to instruct the kernel to use `ahci` module with this device?

Comment: Googling the device ID `[1b21:0624]` led to [this page](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1b21-0624-1b21-1060) which I believe is saying the device is not supported by `ahci` until kernel version 5.16, whereas I am at 5.4.

Comment: See the answer here: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665630/asmedia-sata-controller-106x-not-working-under-ubuntu/769680#769680](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665630/asmedia-sata-controller-106x-not-working-under-ubuntu/769680#769680)