# Problem mounting HDD connected via PCIe SATA Controller

Tags: mount, acpi, pci, sata

I'm using an ASMedia SATA Controller card model 1062.

I've looked at [ASMedia SATA controller 106x not working under ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665630/asmedia-sata-controller-106x-not-working-under-ubuntu) and [ASmedia SATA controller PCIe card not working on ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689013/asmedia-sata-controller-pcie-card-not-working-on-ubuntu) because I thought they were having the same problem. However, my card is indeed using the correct acpi module and not the pata_acpi module.

Here's the output from

```
03:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:1060]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 42
        IOMMU group: 20
        Region 0: I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
        Region 1: I/O ports at e040 [size=4]
        Region 2: I/O ports at e030 [size=8]
        Region 3: I/O ports at e020 [size=4]
        Region 4: I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
        Region 5: Memory at fc810000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
        Expansion ROM at fc800000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee00000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <1us, L1 <8us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM not supported
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABC, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
                         10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
```

I'm just trying to add a new HDD for storing data. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT - The hard drive is just a standard HGST 10 TB drive. I have checked /dev and it's not listed there with the other hard drives. It occurs to me that maybe it will be listed in /dev with a name other than "sd(x)" but if so I can't find what it would be via a Google search.

Thanks.

Comment: please post your `dmesg` somewhere, e.g. at pastebin.com. Would be nice to also get `sudo fdisk -l` output.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - Here's links to the outputs you requested:
https://bruke.net/Storage/documents/dmesg.txt
https://bruke.net/Storage/documents/fdisk.txt

Comment: Please try kernel 6.1.8 if you can at least to confirm whether your HDD is detected or not. If it's still undetected, file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=IO%2FStorage under SATA. I've not detected anything interesting in your dmesg log. Oh, and make sure the HDD works :-)